# Node.js Oracle LDAP TNS Could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: node.js, oracle, ldap, database-connection, node-oracledb

I had connected to oracledb with nodejs with hostname and servicename and it was working fine with below syntax:

```
connection =await oracledb.getConnection({
user: 'username',
password: 'pwd',
connectString: 'hostname:port/servicename'
});
```

Our database details recently changed to LDAP connectivity and I have hence updated the connectString as below:

```
 connection =await oracledb.getConnection({
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pwd',
    connectString:'jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://<LDAP Server>:port/<Database Service Name>,cn=OracleContext,dc=<domain>,dc=com'
    });
```

However I get error: ORA -12154:TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I checked with our DBA and they do not use ORA files and neither did I have those before in my network/admin folder. Do I still need to add the same.
I am new to Oracle DB and I did not find resolutions which helped me on this and hence posting the issue.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jdbc** is Java - not node.js (which is Java**Script**)

Try

```
{
   user: 'username',
   password: 'pwd',
   connectString:'<Database Service Name>'
}
```

You must configure the LDAP settings in `ldap.ora` file, for example like this:

```
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=<domain>,dc=com"
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (<LDAP Server>:port)
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

and set it also in `sqlnet.ora`:

```
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = <domain>.com
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (LDAP, TNSNAMES)
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wernfried Domscheit for your help this helped resolve my error :)